# I'm interested in using "ADB over Wi-Fi"

Tags: android

I'm interested in using "ADB over Wi-Fi" for debugging and troubleshooting my Android Studio application developments?

I already have two tablets that I will like to use for developing instead of using the slow emulator. The problem is that the manufacturer ACER does not provide suitable (Windows 8) ADB compatible driver for them.

I believe the "ADB over WiFi" will make these tablets useful for programming and testing on real devices. I have been searching around but have only found apps requiring a functional USB port on the tablet for the initial configuration.

- +Most apps in Google Play require Rooting and a USB in order to work. I do not want to root AND sadly my USB ports are useless, so the question is:
  Does anyone of you know any other way to do this? Achieving ADB over Wi-Fi without Rooting and without a USB port?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

This one works perfect for me:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=es